# Finding Bessel function zeros by hands

Tags: soft-question, bessel-functions

Which representation and method I can use to find approximately first 4 roots of $J_0$ with pen and paper? How can I do it?

The same question about maximal and minimal points and values?

Background:

[image]

Here you see the graph of Bessel functions $J_n(x)$

I want to justify this sketch for $J_0(x)$, i.e. I want to

1. Find roots, max and min points, maximal and minimal values approximately.
2. The same for its derivative.
3. Prove, that the limit is 0.
4. Prove, that the asymptotic behavior $\simeq \frac{1}{\sqrt{z}}$

Second item of the list is needed, because I know that $J_0'(x) = -J_1(x)$, so I will be able to justify the graph for $J_1$ at the same time.
$3,4$ are basic results, so no problem here.

Answer (score 3):

For the zero's, a long time ago, one of my PhD students used
$$x_n=p+\frac{1}{8p}-\frac{31}{384 p^3}+\cdots \qquad \text{where} \qquad p=  \left(n-\frac{1}{4}\right)\pi$$ which works pretty well as shown below
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 n & \text{estimate} & \text{exact}  \\
 1 & 2.403074548 & 2.404825558 \\
 2 & 5.520037754 & 5.520078112 \\
 3 & 8.653723235 & 8.653727913 \\
 4 & 11.79153341 & 11.79153444 \\
 5 & 14.93091739 & 14.93091771 \\
 6 & 18.07106384 & 18.07106397 \\
 7 & 21.21163657 & 21.21163663 \\
 8 & 24.35247150 & 24.35247153 \\
 9 & 27.49347912 & 27.49347913 \\
 10 & 30.63460646 & 30.63460647
\end{array}
\right)$$

You can approximate the location of the extrema at the mid point, that is to say at $\frac {x_n+x_{n+1}} 2$.